# Why can't -qnorm in sapply?

Tags: r

```
> sapply(c(0.05,0.01),function(k){-qnorm(k)})
[1] 1.644854 2.326348
> -sapply(c(0.05,0.01),qnorm)
[1] 1.644854 2.326348
```

but the following can not run,why `-qnorm` can not run in sapply?

> sapply(c(0.05,0.01),-qnorm)
>       Error in -qnorm : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Because `-qnorm` is not a function, or the name of a function.

Comment: `-` is a unary prefix function in this context and `qnorm` is a function, but `-qnorm` in that context does not result in the interpreter parsing as `function(x) {-(qnorm(x))}` which would have succeeded.

Comment: sapply makes a call to `match.function`, passing *"-qnorm"* as the search parameter, and as Marius said `-qnorm` is not a function name so it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the issue has to do with the fact that `-qnorm(.)` is actually a composite of **two** functions.  First you calculate `qnorm(.)` then you take the `negative`.

`sapply` is expecting a **single** function.

When you use `sapply( <..>,  -qnorm)`  `R` is trying to compute *"minus the function qnorm"*, which makes no sense for functions.
(Just type `-qnorm` and you will get the same error.)

The reason `-qnorm(k)` works is because `R` is calculating `qnorm(k)` to get a number, then taking the negative of that number.

Similarly,  `sapply(<..>, qnorm)` gives a vector.  That's why when you add the negative sign in front of it, you get your desired output.

Comment: He has nearly that exact code as the second command in the question...  Of course, the explanation is correct.  I figured that was covered in the comments of the question.

Comment: ...and i totally missed that.  Whoops!  (Answer edited to reflect)

Answer (score 5):

`Compose` is good for such things:

```
require(functional)
sapply(c(0.05,0.01), Compose(qnorm, `-`))
[1] 1.644854 2.326348
```

Note that back-quotes around the `-` are required here.

Comment: I was unfamiliar with `functional`, Compose seems very practical.  However, in this situation, it seems a bit overkill ;)

Comment: It may seem to be overkill, but (at least for me) it results in a more readable expression.

Comment: Interestingly, I've found two applications for `Compose` since reading this.  Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Also look at `Reduce`, which is the base of `Compose`.  Just as useful, but for different problems.